# useSelector can only be defined inside functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to use `useSelector` with `useEffect` because
`dispatch(searchEvents(location.search))` returns a promise, and only after the promise has resolved, I can use `useSelector()` hooks from `react-redux` because `dispatch` from `useDispatch()` from `react-redux` will update the redux store which I will use to render my list

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [priceFilter, setPriceFilter] = useState("");
  const [eventsList, setEventsList] = useState([]);

 const FetchingEventsList = () => {
     const eventsArray = useSelector((state) => Object.values(state.event));
  setEventsList(eventsArray);
   };
 

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(searchEvents(location.search))
      .then(() => {
      FetchingEventsList()
  
 
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [location.search]);
```

Comment: you can't use hooks inside other hooks. [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: move useSelector out of useEffect.

Comment: ` const FetchingEventsList = () => {
     const eventsArray = useSelector((state) => Object.values(state.event));
  setEventsList(eventsArray);
   };
 

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(searchEvents(location.search))
      .then(() => {
      FetchingEventsList()
  
 
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [location.search]);
`
**i have tried this**

Answer (score 0):

Move `useSelector` outside `useEffect`

```
const [text, setText] = useState("")
const [priceFilter, setPriceFilter] = useState("")
const [eventsList, setEventsList] = useState([])
const eventsArray = useSelector((state) => Object.values(state.event))

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(searchEvents(location.search))
    .then(() => {
        setEventsList(eventsArray)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
}, [location.search])
```

I think you do not need eventsList, so your code can look like

```
const eventsArray = useSelector((state) => Object.values(state.event))

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(searchEvents(location.search))
}, [location.search])
```

React hooks are working only in function root. So you can not use hook in another hook. What I can see in your code when you dispatch `searchEvents` you should update your store, so the `useSelector` hook should update the `eventsArray` in your component. Then I think you will do not need to create a new `eventsList` variable.

Comment: dispatch is returning promise because searchEvents is action creator which uses redux-thunk middleware for api request

Comment: in my code useSelector hook take the previous state from my redux-store because it runs before the promise of dispatch in useEffect resoles